# WebView not working consistently

Tags: android, webview

#### Edit: Strangely works when duplicating the `loadUrl()` line

I'm working with WebViews to gather data from a webpage. Sometimes, the webview just does nothing. I tried many proposes, but actually, none of them works....

Strange: `webview.loadUrl("url...")` doesn't work, but as soon as I call it twice, it works...

#### checkLogin()

```
void checkLogin(final Context context) {

    Log.d("checkLogin()", "Begin of checkLogin()");

    WebView webview = returnNewWebView(context, false);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d("url", url);

            // GOOGLE.COM ACTUALLY WORKS!

            if(url.equals("https://www.google.com/"))
                return;

            Log.d("checkLogin()", "Loading of checkpage finished");

            if(url.contains("loginto.php")) {

                Log.d("checkLogin()", "User is logged out");

                OnLoginCheckListener.onLoginCheckLoggedOut();

            } else {

                Log.d("checkLogin()", "User is logged in");

                OnLoginCheckListener.onLoginCheckLoggedIn();
            }

        }
    });


    String id = sharedPref.getString("id", null);
    String transid = sharedPref.getString("transid", null);

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty("id") || TextUtils.isEmpty("transid")) {
        Log.d("checkLogin()", "No login found, starting LoginActivity()");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else {
        Log.d("checkLogin()", "Probably logged in, checking by loading startpage");
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
         // google actually works -.-
        webview.loadUrl("https://my.login-page.com/index.php?pageid=1&id=" + id + "&transid=" + transid);
    }

}
```

#### returnNewWebView()

private WebView returnNewWebView(Context context, Boolean JSInterface) {

```
    // Prepare a webview

    WebView WebView = new WebView(context);

    if(JSInterface) {
        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "AndroidInterface");
    }

    // We don't need images for data scraping...

    WebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);

    WebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    // Allow cookies

    CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(WebView);
    }

    // Prevent webview not loading
    // or try it...

    WebView.clearCache(true);
    WebView.destroyDrawingCache();

    return WebView;
}
```

As you see, I already tried some stuff in order to prevent it but still, it doesn't work. In that cases, as soon I'm going to put the `loadUrl() / postUrl()`twice, it works.

**What can I do that it works in every single case?**

I would appreciate any tip!
Thank you very much in advance

**logcat (non-filtered)**

I actually see this message then..

```
03-09 07:36:19.061 4111-24251/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeActiveInterval: Error: ongoing, trying to close
```

and this one:

```
03-09 07:36:28.864 29862-3249/? E/accs.GcmPush: initializeApp occur error!
                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
                                                    at iv.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at org.android.agoo.gcm.GcmRegister$1.run(GcmRegister.java:32)
```

and this one too:

```
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

But I can't tell you if they are fired by the app....

Comment: You will need to add more information. Logging. Etc. Where are you adding the Webview in the view hierarchy? If not, then it should be a network request, not a WebView.

Comment: Provide more information to the question. Share a screenshot , etc.

Comment: See my updated answer
Would it be possible to inject Javascript when using Volley? @MartinMarconcini

Comment: Actually works when i duplicate the `loadUrl()` command. What could it be??? @HarshitAgrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the full code for so long and pointed out this :

You are using this -

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
     // google actually works -.-
webview.loadUrl("https://my.login-page.com/index.php?pageid=1&id=" + id + "&transid=" + transid);
```

in your **checkLogin()** method which is simply wrong as because one webview can not display the two urls at same time (as you mentioned it you want to achieve that).

Now according to your code the loading of the first url is overridden by the second url.

In order to achieve the loading of two urls in same webview try to implement this using :

> Threads or some sessionTimeout methods.

**OR**
You can achieve this by using `okhttp` package.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks for going through this... Google Link was just for testing, because then it actually worked.. without google not. I ended up using `okhttp` package.

Comment: @DarioAckermann glad to hear that your problem was resolved :) And I have edited my answer and added okhttp package to the answer so that the users looking for the same problem can have a proper answer.

Comment: @DarioAckermann well for my efforts and time you can atleast upvote or accept my answer  :) so that other users may find the direct answer if they came looking for the same problem.

Comment: I will :-) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

`onPageFinished` is called when the webpage finished loading, but not after all the javascript on the page finished running. Depending on what the page is doing and what you are trying to achieve, it might be that your code is sometimes being executed **before** some essential javascript is executed on that page.

It's not a pretty solution but try adding some delay (like a Handler's `postDelayed()` or `SystemClock.sleep()` - but never on the UI thread!) to your code to see if that is indeed your problem.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated question with sample code. If url is loaded I want to have a look at if it has changed or not (due to redirect to login page). Actually this check gets *never* performed. But loading google.com works! And if I would *not* return it with www.google.com, the other url would work too.... but not solo... Any further tip?